# primeng datatable get value from column

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

am using primeNG datatable. Apart of raw data, i would like to add edit/delete actions. the problem is, i cannot figure out, how to get into data from field. How to get data from field and get it into link?

```
<p-dataTable [(value)]="pois">
<p-column field="value.properties.title" header="title" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
<p-column field="value.properties.description" header="description" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
<p-column field="value.properties.activated" header="activated" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
<p-column field="id" header="actions">
  <template pTemplate>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/poi/edit/' + id<!--id doesnt work--> ]"><span class="icon">{{"lists.edit"|translate}}</span></button>
  </template>
</p-column>
```

Answer (score 4):

i found solution.

```
<p-dataTable [(value)]="pois">
<p-column field="value.properties.title" header="title" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains" [sortable]="true"> </p-column>
<p-column field="value.properties.description" header="description" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="contains" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
<p-column field="value.properties.activated" header="activated" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
<p-column field="id" header="actions">
  <template pTemplate let-col let-node="rowData">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/poi/edit/' + node[col.field] ]">
      <span class="icon">{{"lists.edit"|translate}}</span>
    </button>
  </template>
</p-column>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p-dataTable [(value)]="pois" 
    selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedPois">>  <---add this
```

From component.ts:

```
pois: YourType[];
selectedPois: YourType;
```

In the html:

```
<template pTemplate>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/poi/edit/' + {{selectedRow.id}} ]">
    <span class="icon">{{"lists.edit"|translate}}</span></button>
</template>
```

This should work, but it has not been tested.

Comment: {{selectedRow.id}} doesnt work. Is there any other way to get into "selected" variable?